# Good server-javascript host/framework?

Tags: javascript, serverside-javascript

I'm trying to find a good javascript based web host, as well as a good server-side javascript implementation. I have played some with NodeJS, and it seems very good, but I really don't want to have to write the entire server from scratch. I need a host/framework with the following features (or at least most of them):

1: The ability to run a script continuously on the server while maintaining a continuous dialog with other scripts as well as client pages (through xmlhttprequest).
2: PHP/ASP like functionality.
3: I don't want to have to write an entire server from scratch. I just want to worry about writing my application.

Also, I have recently been looking into Aptana's Jaxer, which seems to be the holy grail from my perspective, but when I go to the web site "www.jaxer.org", it returns a completely irrelevant page. Could somebody please explain this to me?

Thanks,

Chris

Answer (score 1):

I've used https://no.de/ from joyent to host my node.js applications.

For communicating between the client and the server I'd use http://socket.io/ . It's a communication framework that will choose the most appropriate communication method to maintain a connection (continuous dialog) with the client.

For serving static content see this answer for a link to a great article on a simple web server.

[Using node.js as a simple web server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6084360/node-js-as-a-simple-web-server)

Or see this answer that discusses various web application frameworks.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3809539/choosing-a-web-application-framework-using-node-js

Hope this helps, & Good luck on your project!

Answer (score 0):

You could have a look at [Wakanda](http://wakanda.org)

It provides a full stack including, the server, the studio, and the client framework, all in a very consistent way.

There is a related question I answered on stackoverflow about [where to host Wakanda applications](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9385080/where-to-host-wakanda-a-client-server-side-pure-js-framework/9393843#9393843), and another one comparing [different existing server-side JavaScript solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1992367/best-server-side-javascript-servers/7192746#7192746)