# Where to host Wakanda [a client/server side pure JS 'framework']?

Tags: javascript, frameworks, wakanda

I recently found [Wakanda](http://www.wakanda.org/) by means of a reference in a blog post. It's a solution to develop pure JavaScript data-driven application - **JS at the client- and the server-side**. As far as I tested it, the project looks promising. Wakanda's JS [framework WAF](https://github.com/Wakanda/WAF/wiki) is open-source.

Since I failed to find an answer on Wakanda's site: **Are there already any dedicated hosting providers available?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no "dedicated" hosting company yet (Wakanda is still in beta)

Some Wakanda users have been using:

- Amazon EC2
- Rackspace
- Gandi VPS ([see the TechWireNews article](http://techwirenews.com/wakanda-server-on-gandi-vps/))
- Mac Mini vault ([see on the forum](http://forum.wakanda.org/showthread.php?1003-Hosting-really-good-dedicated-server-option))

A blog post should come soon.

Answer (score 2):

I don't believe you are going to find a web hosting company dedicated to hosting a wakanda server. Your best bet is to get a VPS from a proper web hosting company (like linode.com), and ramp it up as you need it. If you need something more powerful, grab a dedicated from any reputable provider (ie: softlayer.com).

Answer (score 1):

Wakanda has an official Platform as a Service (PaaS) called ***Wakanda Cloud*** available at [console.wakanda.io](https://console.wakanda.io)

The documentation for *Wakanda Cloud* is available at [cloud-docs.wakanda.io](http://cloud-docs.wakanda.io/en/latest/)

The road map for *Wakanda Cloud* is hosted on [trello](https://trello.com/b/0DRtt76j/wakanda-cloud-roadmap)