# connecting wakanda to wamp server

Tags: javascript, web-applications, wampserver, wakanda

I'm using wakanda as my IDE and I just started and found out that it has its own wakanda server, this IDE is so simple, easy after I tried sencha Extjs. One problem I was searching for and I couldn't find until now, is how to connect my wakanda IDE to any other server, but the one it has, because if I want to launch my work, I won't launch it locally...

I tried finding anything at their website [here](http://www.wakanda.org/), but couldn't find any help at this point...

Any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The GUI Designer of the Wakanda studio use widgets from the Wakanda framework bound together and to the server using datasources. The datasources use a dataprovider to communicate with the WakandaDB REST API. WakandaDB, even if it could be accessed from LAMP or WAMP platforms, is made accessible through the Web by the Wakanda Server without the need of any external HTTP server.

Wakanda Server is not yet available in standard Shared Hosting offers, but most Hosting companies propose VPS and/or dedicated server offers as well which suit well with Wakanda.

We also recently provided a Webinar about "Deploying Wakanda apps to the Cloud":
http://go.4d.com/deploying-on-the-cloud-webinar.html

Our own team successfully tested Wakanda on Windows Azure and Amazon. Wakanda unit tests are executed on daily basis using such cloud providers.

Note that I also previously provided a similar answer on stackoverflow :-)

-> [Where to host Wakanda [a client/server side pure JS 'framework']?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9385080/where-to-host-wakanda-a-client-server-side-pure-js-framework/9393843#9393843)