# NodeJS : make requests to server and get the result

Tags: javascript, node.js, cordova

Is it possible to execute `Javascript` on server side and to get the result on a client ?

If it is possible, how can i make the request to the dedicated `Javascript` file from my client ?

In fact, i have created a mobile application with embeeded `Javascript`, (using Phonegap) but i would like to put all Javascript files on the server and make some requests to the server to get the result.

Thanks for your help

Comment: This link might helpful to you [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1476967/pros-and-cons-of-serverside-javascript-implementation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1476967/pros-and-cons-of-serverside-javascript-implementation)

Comment: This one too [https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Server-Side_JavaScript/Walkthrough](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Server-Side_JavaScript/Walkthrough)

Comment: Check with node.js [http://www.hongkiat.com/blog/node-js-server-side-javascript/](http://www.hongkiat.com/blog/node-js-server-side-javascript/)

Answer (score 0):

See You have to create a Web Service on the Server Side to enable the Client(Phonegap App) to make an Ajax request and fetch some data.

Earlier you could have written a web service using programming languages like PHP, .NET, Java, Ruby, Python etc. But [NodeJS](http://nodejs.org) provides the flexibility of writing REST Based web services in Javascript itself.

You can learn about it here: http://appsonmob.com/nodejs-expressjs-mysql/